# OpenID-style authentication for a Client/Server game?

Tags: security, authentication

For a particular client/server game written in C++, I would like to develop a 'Login Server', so players can be individually tracked by a game server.  However, I am averse to reinventing the wheel, and although I have unorthadox requirements, I want to know if what I am looking for has an already established implementation.

What I want is something like OpenID, where there is no authoritative login server.  I want there to potentially be many login servers, and all a game server knows for sure is that the guy who used a specific login server with a specific username is the same as the guy who used that login server with that username last time.

Well, why not use OpenID, since I mentioned it by name?  It's too web-centric.  I don't want to put a browser in my game or in the launcher in order for people to pass their credentials to the login server when they want to play on a specific game server.  In fact, a system that is agnostic to the protocol would be preferred, so the login server, game client and game server can all communicate using the same UDP infrastructure that the game client and server already has in place.

Some guidance in this area would be appreciated.  I'd really prefer not to have to come up with the entire system myself, because authentication and security are tough problems.

Answer (score 0):

OpenID binds your users to particular servers. For example, if a user comes from a `http://openid.net/theusername` you can store this information but from this time, the user just **has** to use the same authentication server and if the server is down, there is a difficult scenario on how to migrate an account to another identity (another provider).

On the other hand, if you rely on Oauth2 authentication and make email your primary recognized identity, users could authenticate with dozen of different providers you set up (Google, Facebook, Twitter, Linkedin) and you can trust providers that the email has been verified prior to authentication (this is how identity providers work).

I would then strongly recommend OAuth2. You still doesn't impose any specific provider and let your users to pick up their favourite one but in the same time you have quite reliable information, email, which can be used as a communication channel to send any information from your application to your users.

Comment: It seems like OAuth2 is still in draft stages, and it also appears that it leaves transport security to the implementation...which might be difficult and/or error-prone to implement on top of UDP.

Comment: It could be in draft which doesn't stop everybody from implementing it. Yes, the security depends on tcp/ssl.